# variable not defined in range

Tags: python, macros

I am just start learning Python today because I need to create a macro in PARAVIEW. 
I have several grid files which name is namefile.timestep (ex: p3d.030000)
I want to open this PLOT3D files with a macro, take a picture of the grid and then create a movie with these pictures.

The first thing that I need to know to open these files is their names (including the path ex: home/enrico/desktop/p3d.030000).
I want a macro that open a GUI in which I insert the folder path, the root name of the files (ex:p3d) and the time steps (I give the first time step, the interval and the number of files). Whit these data I can create the complete paths. Then I will open them one at the time to create a snapchat and save this figure in a file .png. 
Then with this picture I will create a movie (still to figure out how)
I am stuck with the construction of the complete folder path. The code tell me that a variable firsttimestep is not defined inside the for cycle.

I do not know what I am doing wrong. Probably is a simple problem, but I am a beginner.
Thanks for your help

```
#simple GUI
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):

 def __init__(self,master):
    "Initialize the Frame"
    Frame.__init__(self,master)
    self.grid()
    inp=self.create_widgets()

 def create_widgets(self):  
    self.instruction=Label(self, text="Enter the folder PATH")
    self.instruction.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2,sticky=W)
    self.path=Entry(self)
    self.path.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=W)

    self.instruction=Label(self, text="Enter the PLOT3D file name")
    self.instruction.grid(row=3,column=0,columnspan=2,sticky=W)
    self.plot3dname=Entry(self)
    self.plot3dname.grid(row=4,column=1,sticky=W)

    self.instruction=Label(self, text="Enter number of solution and grid files")
    self.instruction.grid(row=5,column=0,columnspan=2,sticky=W)
    self.numfiles=Entry(self)
    self.numfiles.grid(row=6,column=1,sticky=W)

    self.instruction=Label(self, text="Enter time step interval")
    self.instruction.grid(row=7,column=0,columnspan=2,sticky=W)
    self.numtimestep=Entry(self)
    self.numtimestep.grid(row=8,column=1,sticky=W)   

    self.instruction=Label(self, text="Enter first time step")
    self.instruction.grid(row=9,column=0,columnspan=2,sticky=W)
    self.firsttimestep=Entry(self)
    self.firsttimestep.grid(row=10,column=1,sticky=W)

    self.save_button=Button(root, text="Save input", command=self.save)
    self.save_button.grid(row=11,column=0,sticky=W)

    self.quit_button=Button(root, text="Quit", command=quit)
    self.quit_button.grid(row=12,column=0,sticky=W)

 def save(self):
     pathvalue    =self.path.get()       
     plot3dname   =self.plot3dname.get()    
     numfiles     =int(self.numfiles.get())
     stepinterval =int(self.numtimestep.get())  
     firsttimestep=int(self.firsttimestep.get())
     print(pathvalue)
     print(plot3dname)
     print(numfiles)
     print(stepinterval)     
     print(firsttimestep)       
     # create root file name 
     RootGridName=pathvalue + '.'+ plot3dname
     for x in range(firsttimestep,laststep,stepinterval):
         s="{:06d}".format(x)
         # Filename rooth.num ex:  '/usr/bin/p3d.010000'
         FileName = RootGridName + s
         print(FileName)

 def quit():
     root.destroy()          

 root =Tk()
 root.title("Path")
 root.geometry("400x400")
 app=Application(root)
 root.mainloop()
```

When compile I receive the error:

```
for x in range(firsttimestep,laststep,stepinterval):
NameError: name 'firsttimestep' is not defined
```

Comment: You used `self` to access it earlier. Why did you think you could get away without it this time?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting that error? When I run this, I get laststep is not defined, not `firsttimestep` .

Comment: indeed, laststep isn't defined anywhere

Comment: I don't think you're getting that error. A tip would be to actually cut and paste the error instead of just trying to write it by hand (often it gets wrong then, and often it's missing important information).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step in debugging is to assume the error message is telling you the literal truth. In this case the error message is telling you precisely what's wrong.

The error is saying that `laststep` is not defined (even though you claim in the question that the error references a different variable). Scanning your code, I can see no place where you are defining it. You must define a variable before you use it.

Comment: Yes, it is true. I did not defined laststep. Now it works. Thanks! It was a silly mistake.